# INSERT unless date is the same

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, where-clause, sql-insert

Is it possible (in Postgres) to do the following 2 `INSERT`s, or something that's logically equivalent (the proposed `INSERT`s don't work as they are, but maybe they can be slightly modified?):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table01(
  userid     int8 NOT NULL,
  save       date NOT NULL,
  followers  int4
);
CREATE  UNIQUE INDEX  ON table01 (userid,save);
```

- `INSERT` 0:

```
INSERT  INTO table01 (userid,save,followers)  VALUES (%s,%s,%s)
ON CONFLICT (userid)  DO  INSERT INTO table01 (userid,save,followers) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)
WHERE table01.save!=save;
```

- `INSERT` 1:

```
INSERT  INTO table01 (userid,save,followers)  VALUES (%s,%s,%s)  WHERE table01.save!=save;
```

The logic is:

- Try to insert a row
- If there's a conflict of `userid`, then insert the row anyway UNLESS the **date** (`save`) is the same

---

Summary:

0. Are the 2 shown `INSERT`s (or something equivalent) possible?
1. Is it possible to do `ON CONFLICT DO INSERT` (just like one does `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE`)?
2. Is it possible to do `INSERT INTO WHERE` (just like one does `SELECT FROM WHERE`)?

Comment: You can add a unique constraint on (user_id, save), if `save` is your date column, so that only the case you wanted to fail will fail.  But `user_id` will not be unique in the table. I noticed you did create that constraint.  So why isn't that exactly what you wanted?  Just remove the `ON CONFLICT` clause.

Comment: Are you trying to do something like `INSERT IGNORE`, as MySQL has, to ignore the conflict case?  Isn't that done with `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`?

Comment: @JonArmstrong Yes, that's the same solution I've arrived at.

Answer (score 2):

A simple `insert` would seem to do what you want:

```
INSERT  INTO table01 (userid, save, followers)
    VALUES (%s, %s, %s);
```

This will insert a new row unless the `userid`/`save` pair is already there.  In that case, it would generate an error.  If you don't want an error, you can use `on conflict do nothing`:

```
INSERT  INTO table01 (userid, save, followers)
    VALUES (%s, %s, %s)
    ON CONFLICT (userid, save) DO NOTHING;
```

Comment: Thanks. What about `INSERT INTO WHERE`? How can that be implemented?

Comment: @étale-cohomology . . . (1) It is not SQL.  (2) It is not needed to do what you want.